# NuGet Packages claiming to not be correctly installed

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have a project that references

```
WindowsAzure.ServiceBus
```

However, when I rebuild the project, I get the error:

> 1>C:\Users\xyz\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\MyProject\Class.cs(1,17,1,27): error
>   CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceBus' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> 1>C:\Users\xyz\documents\visual studio
>   2017\Projects\MyProject\Class.cs(12,24,12,38): error
>   CS0246: The type or namespace name 'EventHubClient' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I've removed and restored the packages directory for the solution, but to no avail.  I've tried re-installing the NuGet packages:

```
Update-Package -reinstall
```

Which claimed to successfully restore the package.  I can `Build` the project successfully, but a `Rebuild` fails.  Issuing an MSBuild in the command prompt also fails.

Just to alay any theories that there's no using statement, Class.cs:

```
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
```

I'm at a loss to how to progress with this; can anyone offer any ideas where to go next?

Comment: Other than using statements can you do a Solution wide search of Microsoft.ServiceBus and EventHubClient. They might have been used with Fully Qualified namespace.

Comment: Other thing that comes to my mind is to Upgrade you .NET Framework version. If nuget dll was build for higher .NEt runtime, there is just a Warning message printed in Output window and Error window stays clear. But Build fails.

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava spot on - the Framework was on version 4.5 - soon as I upgraded it started working.  If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting for the points :) (I love them)

Other thing that comes to my mind is to Upgrade your .NET Framework version. If nuget dll was build for higher .NET runtime, there is just a Warning message printed in Output window and Error window stays clear. But Build fails.